# How to get rank from full-text search query with Linq to SQL?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, full-text-search

I am using Linq to SQL to call a stored procedure which runs a full-text search and returns the rank plus a few specific columns from the table `Article`.  The rank column is the rank returned from the SQL function FREETEXTTABLE().  I've added this sproc to the O/R designer with return type `Article`.

This is working to get the columns I need; however, it discards the ranking of each search result.  I'd like to get this information so I can display it to the user.

So far, I've tried creating a new class `RankedArticle` which inherits from `Article` and adds the column `Rank`, then changing the return type of my sproc mapping to `RankedArticle`.  When I try this, an InvalidOperationException gets thrown:

> Data member 'Int32 ArticleID' of type 'Heap.Models.Article' is not part of the mapping for type 'RankedArticle'. Is the member above the root of an inheritance hierarchy?

If I let the O/R designer set the sproc's own return type, it returns an int rather than a "SearchArticlesByKeywordResult" object.  I'm not sure why this is, perhaps because the sproc is returning a union?  Here is my procedure:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
(
    SELECT ftt.[rank] as [Rank], ArticleID, Subject
    FROM Article
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE( Article, (Subject, Body), @KeywordList ) AS ftt
    ON ftt.[key] = Article.ArticleID

    UNION

    SELECT ftt.[rank] as [Rank], Article.ArticleID as ArticleID, Article.Subject as Subject
    FROM Article
    INNER JOIN Solution ON Solution.ArticleID = Article.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE( Solution, Body, @KeywordList ) AS ftt
    ON ftt.[key] = Solution.SolutionID
)
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
END
```

I can't seem to find any other questions or Google results from people trying to get the rank column, so I'm probably missing something obvious here.

Comment: When you add a sproc to the linq to sql designer, it creates its own return type. Why are you mapping it to Article?

Comment: .. it creates its own return type which should have the rank as a property.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I tried that when I just drag the sproc into the O/R designer, it makes it return an int rather than a SearchArticlesByKeywordResult object.  I've edited the question too.

Comment: Go to sql management studio and call your stored procedure with a @keywordlist as null. Do you see any error? Linq to SQL, in addition to other things, calls the sproc with null to discover the return columns.

Comment: You're right; I was not aware that's how it worked.  I modified my sproc to not error on a null input parameter and now it generated a result type.  That result type has exactly what I needed.  If you post your help as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to sql management studio and call your stored procedure with a @keywordlist as null. Do you see any error? Linq to SQL, in addition to other things, calls the sproc with null to discover the return columns.

Comment: The sproc was erroring on a null input, I hadn't considered that. I made it return the normal result list on null input, and now an auto-generated result type gets generated when I add the sproc to the O/R designer.  Thanks!